# Get logs from FrameworkStatsLog write

Tags: android, logcat

Say below [code](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/power/stats/BatteryStatsImpl.java;l=4437?q=FrameworkStatsLog.write&ss=android) from android:

```
FrameworkStatsLog.write(FrameworkStatsLog.UID_PROCESS_STATE_CHANGED, uid,
            ActivityManager.processStateAmToProto(state));
    getUidStatsLocked(parentUid, elapsedRealtimeMs, uptimeMs)
            .updateUidProcessStateLocked(state, elapsedRealtimeMs, uptimeMs);
}
```

How can I get the logs,  `adb logcat` do not find such logs.